# Windows phone 8 admob white surrounding in Landscape

Tags: windows-phone-8, admob, landscape

When I have a Admob Adview with this code:

```
<GoogleAds:AdView 
   Name="bottomAd"
   AdUnitID="ca-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
   Format="Banner"
   ReceivedAd="OnAdReceived"
   FailedToReceiveAd="OnFailedToReceiveAd"
   VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
```

But when I start my app **in Landscape mode** I get a white surrounding around my `AdView`. 
Sometimes the `AdView` fills the complete size, but some ads are too small like this:

Screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVjnD.png

Comment: Looks like your container for the `AdView` is using a percentage for height/width possibly? So when in landscape mode the container grows in size but the `AdView` does not?

Comment: Does it sometimes fill the complete size in landscape mode? Or is it only correct in Portrait mode? I think I mis-read that the first time.

Comment: The Container for my Adview is just <Grid> </Grid>, so I think it shouldn't scale.
Sometimes it fills complete in Landscape but most often not. I think it's because of different Adtypes, because the ones that fill complete have more options if you click them.

Comment: No I did not, I just went with the Interstitial ads instead.

Answer (score 0):

I used to worry about it but I guess it's about text / image ads, image ads are big but texts aren't... We should contact google for them to fix text ads...